# Why does "std::begin()" always return "const_iterator" in such a case?

Tags: c++, c++11, iterator, standards, type-safety

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    vector<int> coll;

    decltype(std::begin(std::declval<vector<int>>()))
        pos_1 = coll.begin();
    auto pos_2 = coll.begin();

    cout << typeid(decltype(pos_1)).name() << endl;
    cout << typeid(decltype(pos_2)).name() << endl;
}
```

My compiler is clang 4.0. The output is:

> ```
> class std::_Vector_const_iterator<class std::_Vector_val<struct std::_Simple_types<int> > >
> class std::_Vector_iterator<class std::_Vector_val<struct std::_Simple_types<int> > >
> ```

That means: `pos_1 = pos_2;` is ok, while `pos_2 = pos_1;` is not ok.

**Why does `std::begin()` always return `const_iterator` rather than `iterator` in such a case?**

Comment: My guess is it's because it's because youre deducing the type of `pos_1` using a temporary. They only bind to const references and all that, which is where the const comes in the play.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The function call:

```
std::declval<std::vector<int>>()
```

results in an rvalue expression that can be denoted as:

```
std::vector<int>&&
```

The compiler has two (generic) overloads of `std::begin` to choose from ([[iterator.range]](http://eel.is/c++draft/iterator.range)):

```
template <class C> 
auto begin(C& c) -> decltype(c.begin());        // #1

template <class C> 
auto begin(const C& c) -> decltype(c.begin());  // #2
```

For an rvalue expression, only the second overload (#2) is viable -- an rvalue cannot be bound by a non-const lvalue reference. The const qualification of the referenced type implies that the compiler will use the const qualified overload of the `begin` member function:

```
const_iterator begin() const noexcept;
//                     ~~~~^
```

which returns an instance of type `const_iterator`.

You can change that behavior by requesting an lvalue expression of `std::vector<int>` from the `std::declval` call:

```
decltype(std::begin(std::declval<std::vector<int>&>())) pos_1 = coll.begin();
//                                             ~~^~~
```

Comment: Interesting to note: if the non-`static` member version of `begin` had been used, the mutable version would have been preferred, returning `iterator`. This is one way member and non-member functions differ

Comment: @KABoissonneault You mean `std::declval<std::vector<int>>().begin()` ? Yes, that's because of [\[over.match.funcs\]/p5.1](http://eel.is/c++draft/over.match.funcs#5.1).

Answer (score 3):

if you have `Type&&` (a temporary) then overload-resolution
will prefer `const Type&` over `Type&`, since
a temporary wont bind to a non-const lvalue-reference